# Retrieving data in table using Web Safe URL title

Tags: url, routes, data-retrieval

I am looking for another solution in retrieving a data from the table using a web-safe url

here is a rough example of my url:

```
https://example.com/this-is-the-blog-title-and-has-no-unallowed-characters
```

Another example is how quora uses this kind of method in their url structures.

```
https://www.quora.com/How-far-is-the-Moon-from-Earth
```

The solution I used is to store a web-safe version of the "title" in the table under the column name "web_safe_title".

**Acutal blog title:** 
What's the distance of the moon from earth?

**Web safe title:** whats-the-distance-of-the-moon-from-earth

and the web safe title is what I use for anchor tags and for retrieving the data from the table.

The problem though is that, I personally think that the way that I did it is not efficient especially when a time comes where I have to change the actual title of the blog post. If i change the title, I would also change the web-safe title to match the new one, thus making previous/older links that uses it obsolete.

I just want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

I am using CodeIgniter version 3.1.8 and MySQL for my database.

Note: *I do not want to use the "id" of the post in the url to retrieve the data. I want it to be clean, only the site name and the blog title for the url.*

Comment: in route.php set $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE; now access the url with dashes works

Comment: You may have misunderstood my problem, I am sorry if my post was not clear because english is not my first language. 

I can already do it, the question I want to ask is, is there a more efficient way of querying for the data without using the "web_safe_title"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below routing to fix your problem. change the controller name and function name as per your class.

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'controller_name/function_name/$1';
```

Comment: sorry if you have misunderstood my post, my actual problem is that I am looking for a new way of searching the database using the web-safe titles. I do not have any problems with the dashes from the url